# How can I send a query to an IQuerable method on an ASP.NET controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am using Entity Framework 6 and trying to get some data from my controller. The data is from a table of words which has a key of `WordId` (the actual words).

My controller has this method:

```
[Route("Get")]
public IQueryable<Word> Get()
{
   return db.Words;
}
```

Here’s my `Word` object:

```
    public class Word
    {
        public string WordId { get; set; } // WordId (Primary key) (length: 20)
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    }
```

Is there a way that I can use this method to just get those words that have a first character between A and E ?

Comment: Never expose Entities to controllers.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but in this case I will add some authentication to the method so it’s just available to the admin role.  Just didn’t show the authentication here.

Answer (score 0):

Never return `Entity` or `IQueryables` from the controller, instead create a model and return it as mentioned below:

```
string matchStr = "abcde";

[Route("Get")]
public List<WordModel> Get()
{      
    return db.Words.Where(p=>matchStr.ToUpper().Contains(p.UniqueID.ToUpper().FirstOrDefault())).Select(p=>new WordModel(){
    WordId  = p.WordId,
    CategoryId  = p.CategoryId 
    }).ToList();
}
```

Create a model class `WordModel`, as

```
public class WordModel
{
    public string WordId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sophia. It is a good idea to expose view models (designed based on the view) rather than the actual entities. Lets assume WordVm is that in your case. The return type form the controller action will be a List. Add a reporsitory or a manager class that will be called from your action method that returns your result. I am creating a manager that has access to the db context class with the Word entity.

```
[Route("Get")]
public List<WordVm> Get()
{

    var manager = new WordsManager()

   return manager.GetWords();
}



  public class WordsManager
  {
     public List<WordVm> GetWords()
     {
       return repo.Words.Where(a => {
           var t = a.Trim().ToUpper().Substring(0, 1)[0]; 
           return t >= 'A' && t <= 'E';
          }).ToList();
     }
   }
```

Thank you,
Soma.